# Generator of an ideal $I= (\{f_j\})$ is the monic greatest common divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Identify the following rings:
> (a) $\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$,   (b) $\mathbf{Z}[x]/(2x^2-4,4x-5)$.

For part $(a)$ we have $2(x^2-3)=x\left(2x+4\right)-2\left(2x+4\right)+2$, so $2=0$ in our ring so we get $\mathbf{Z}[x] /(x^2-3,2x+4) \simeq \mathbf{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1,0) = \mathbf{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$.

For part $(b)$ we have $8\left(2x^2-4\right)=4x\left(4x-5\right)+5\left(4x-5\right)-7$ so $7= 0$ in our ring and like in part $(a)$ we get $\mathbf{Z}[x]/(2x^2-4,4x-5) \simeq \mathbf{Z}_7[x]/(2x^2+3, 4x+2)$. Now also we have that $2(2x^2+3) + 0(4x+2) = x+4$ so $x+4 \in (2x^2+3, 4x+2)$, but is it so that $(2x^2+3,4x+2)=(x+4)$ so that the final result is $\mathbf{Z}_7[x]/(x+4)$?

I think I have seen a result that states that for an ideal $I=(\{f_j\})$ of polynomials the monic generator is the greatest common divisor of all $f_j's$? Is there some kind of restrictions on $f_j's$, for example can the belong to any ring $R[x]$ or is it neccessary that they belong to a field $k[x]$?

The problem is from an old algebra exam on a course following Michael Artin's book.

Comment: You know this will be so because you are in a PID, and $k$ being field is enough to guarantee $k[X]$ is PID

Comment: Note that this cannot however be extended to multivariate polynomials or polynomials over a more general ring

Comment: Yes, but how can I be sure that $(x+4)$ is the correct monic to generate $(2x^2+3, 4x+2)$? Since I'm in $k[x]$ I have that every ideal $I$ is generated by single element, but It's not neccessarily $(x+4)$. @Evaristo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that, if $k$ is a field, $k[X]$ is a PID. In this case, Bézout's Identity holds, which means that, for two polynomials $p,q\in k[X]$, there exist  polynomials $a,b\in k[X]$ such that $ap + bq = \gcd{\{p,q\}}$. Observe that this means $\gcd\{p,q\}\in (p,q)$, and so $(\gcd\{p, q\})\subseteq(p,q)$. Now, as $\gcd\{p,q\}$ divides $p$, $\exists r\in k[X]$ such that $p = r\gcd\{p,q\}$, and so $p\in(\gcd\{p,q\})\implies (p)\subseteq (\gcd\{p,q\})$. The same trivially follows for $q$, and so $(\gcd\{p,q\})$ is contained in $(p,q)$ and contains $(p)$ and $(q)$. As $(p,q)$ is the smallest ideal containing $(p)$ and $(q)$, it must mean $(\gcd\{p,q\}) = (p,q)$